# Segment parts of a picture

Tags: image-processing

I remember that there was some thread of this sort, but I could not find it, so I hope it's ok to open a new thread.

I want to segment pictures of the brain, i.e. I only want the area within the skull without the bones (all the grey matter/pixels. White parts are bones of the skull).

I have the following two pictures. In the first picture I also want all the grey parts, but you see that there are some white parts intermingled between. So basically the algorithm should segment four different images. In the second pictures it seems to be easier.

Can you guys give me a hint to a function or some examples or threads?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The second one is super easy. You could do it with just `Binarize` or your could do something like `DeleteSmallComponents@MorphologicalBinarize[img, {0.8, 0.9}]`. The first one is another beast because those four segments aren't properly enclosed.

Comment: Try `DeleteBorderComponents@
 ImageSubtract[i1, Closing[MorphologicalBinarize[i1, {0.9, .99}], 5]]` on the first... where `i1` is the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copying the first image into symbol `i1`:

```
DeleteBorderComponents@ImageSubtract[i1, Closing[MorphologicalBinarize[i1, {0.9, .99}], 5]]
```

[image]

Second is pretty trivial, see *Pickett*'s comment...

Comment: ahh MorphologicalBinarize was what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @holistic: There's probably a dozen ways to do this, when you have the time, explore the various image-related functions, and *play with them* - that's how to get a good feel for them...